# How to imperatively send a form with multiple fields using React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with multiple fields and I want the application's state to change when a submit button is clicked.

I've tried different combinations of code using 1 or 4 (number of form fields) nodes, but haven't been able to add the Item to the item array (declared on another class).

I'm also not exactly sure where `onSubmit = {this.onSubmit.bind(this)}` should go. I've tried putting it where it is and in the last input tag.

Here's the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class ItemForm extends Component{
  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const node = this.refs.item //not sure if we should have 1 node or 4 nodes
    const itemName = node.value; //we need to do this for name, photo, price and donation.
    this.props.addItem(itemName);
    node.value='';
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit.bind(this)} ref='item'>
        Nombre: <input
          type = "text"
        /><br/>
        Precio: <input
          type = "text"
        /><br/>
        Donación: <input
          type = "range" min = "10" max = "100" step = "10"
        /><br/>
        Foto: <input
          type = "file"
        /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Vender"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ItemForm.propTypes={
  addItem: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default ItemForm
```

Answer (score 1):

The react way of doing it is make all the inputs as controlled components. The controlled component store state.

```
Nombre: <input
          type = "text"
          value={this.state.nombre}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ nombre: e.target.value })}
        />
```

In onSubmit, pick all these state values.

```
onSubmit() {
 // do validations.
 this.props.addItem(this.state.nombre); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could bind the inputs' values to the state and then do what you need:

```
class ItemForm extends Component{

  handleNombreChange(e) {
    this.setState({ nombre: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    this.props.addItem(this.state.nombre);
    this.state.nombre = '';
  }

  getInitialState(){
      return { nombre: "" };
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
        Nombre: <input
          type = "text" 
          value={this.state.nombre} 
          onChange={this.handleNombreChange.bind(this)}
        /><br/>
        Precio: <input
          type = "text"
        /><br/>
        Donación: <input
          type = "range" min = "10" max = "100" step = "10"
        /><br/>
        Foto: <input
          type = "file"
        /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Vender"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```